# LogMessage in VB6

Tags: vb6

this might seem a very very foolish question ..but the fact is i am totally new to VB and got least knowledge of it. i have to make some changes in a code . i need to know that is LogMessage an in-built or predefined function(or method or class) like print f in C. if so.. then why is it inherently been defined in a code ....like this:

```
                Sub LogMessage(From As String, Msg As String)
                txtLog.Text = txtLog.Text & From & ": " & Msg & CRLF
                txtLog.SelectionStart = txtLog.Text.Length
                End Sub
```

Comment: You might be getting it confused with something like `MsgBox`, perhaps.

Comment: Looks like VFred to me: `txtLog.Text.Length`  You may want to retitle and retag this question.

Answer (score 2):

it is not a pre-defined function/method.

when you see it defined with only a 'Sub' or 'Function' word in front of it it means that is is user-written code.

bon chance